# Why do I get these errors using yarn install after "create-react-app"?

Tags: create-react-app

I made a new folder and then ran "create-react-app". (This was in Windows 10.)
Then I copied a package.json file from another folder that has running code that had been made with "create-react-app" a few weeks earlier. Then I ran "yarn install" to update the new app with all the node_modules required to duplicate the older app. Why do I get many many errors like those shown below in the console display?

Note: I can't show the complete unformatted display is as it was received, since stackoverflow won't let me post it. So here are a few lines I formatted.

```
ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)\nnode-pre-gyp 
ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)\nnode-pre-gyp 
ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)\nnode-pre-gyp
ERR! build error \nnode-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\\Users\\Bruce\\Dropbox\\Projects BlueDuck\\Blue-Duck-Beta-Test\\node_modules\\fsevents\\lib\\binding\\Release\\node-v48-win32-x64\\fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=C:\\Users\\Bruce\\Dropbox\\Projects BlueDuck\\Blue-Duck-Beta-Test\\node_modules\\fsevents\\lib\\binding\\Release\\node-v48-win32-x64' (1)\nnode-pre-gyp
ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\\Users\\Bruce\\Dropbox\\Projects BlueDuck\\Blue-Duck-Beta-Test\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\lib\\util\\compile.js:83:29)\nnode-pre-gyp
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of npm are you running? If it's 5+, try:

```
npm i -g npm@4
```

From [this thread](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2558)